# May I store View objects in instance fields?

Tags: java, android

I've got an Activity class. It should be really nice to find all the views I need in `onCreate`, and then just reference these fields, without calling `findViewById`. But is it OK to do so?

Can't views be assigned different objects at runtime? E.g., is it always true that `findViewById(res1) == findViewById(res1)` at any time?

Comment: Hi Andy... Most code samples do just that, call findViewById in onCreate and have an instance variable that references the view.

Comment: @JAL: I know that, but it's still interesting if what they're doing is right=)

Comment: OK. Another way to look at this is that you cannot pass parameters to the constructor of an Activity. onCreate IS the constructor and that is where you can initialize the view variables. I have this stupid experiment online. https://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/stupid

Comment: Yes. If you're using Fragments (with retained instance) do not retain view or any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instance variables for your views in an Activity. And

```
findViewById(res1) == findViewById(res1)
```

is true as long as the layout is not inflated again or other changes (replacing views) are made to the content view.

But do not keep references to views in objects that will live longer than the activity holding the views. Like in an Singleton! (see [see Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html))

Comment: This may be helpful: the method setContentView *does* inflate the view and the reference will change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. This is how I've seen it done 90% of the time at my work. Ex.

private ImageView mSomeImage;

public class activ extends Activity{

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saveinstancestate){
    Inialize your views here.
}
```

}

Only do this if you need to, and prefix member variables with m.

Does this help?